# Show GMSPolyline Title On Tap

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google Maps SDK for an iOS application of mine.

I configured it so that when a tap occurs on a `GMSMarker`, it shows it's title. It's working alright.

I want to do the same for `GMSPolyline`s but couldn't figure out how. The lines's `tappable` property is set to `true`.

How can I achieve this. Thanks.

P.S. coding with Swift 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conform to the protocol `GMSMapViewDelegate`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate {
  ...
}
```

Set the `ViewController` to be the delegate of your map view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  ...
  viewMap.delegate = self
}
```

Use the method `mapView:didTapOverlay:`

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapOverlay overlay: GMSOverlay) {
  print(overlay.title)
}
```

This method is called whenever a tap is detected inside the map view.

For more information: [GMSOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_overlay#properties)

Comment: wow, that was easy. thanks. also made some edits for better clarity.

Comment: So how to display overlay title on the map ?

Comment: tapping on the overlay doesn't show the title, did you figure this out?